Is there a way to stream a video to Google Gemini API?
I am building an API in FastAPI that receives a streaming video in the request. I need to send the video content to the Google Gemini API. I know that it is possible to generate content by the Gemini in a streaming mode, but I am not sure if it is possible to stream the input into the API.
I currently have a code similar to the following:
async for chunk in request.stream():
    model = GenerativeModel("gemini-1.5-pro-preview-0409")
    generation_config = {
        "max_output_tokens": 8192,
        "temperature": 1,
        "top_p": 0.95,
    }
    video = Part.from_data(
        mime_type="video/mp4",
        data=base64.b64encode(chunk).decode("utf-8"),
    )
    responses = model.generate_content(
        [prompt, video],
        generation_config=generation_config,
        stream=True,
    )
    for response in responses:
        print(response.text)

However, it throws an error with the following content:
raise exceptions.from_grpc_error(exc) from exc
google.api_core.exceptions.InvalidArgument: 400 Request contains an invalid argument.

Does anybody know if there is a way to stream a video content into the Gemini API? If it is not possible, could you provide any alternative solutions if possible?
